# How to do anything with qt 3d?

Tags: qt3d

I'm completely new to programming and Qt. I read about Qt 3d, but I have no idea how to do anything with it. All I need is a simple cuboid which I can move with a tilt sensor. I'm using qt 5.6.

I tried to understand the examples, but there they always use stuff I don't know.

```
// Cuboid shape data
Qt3DRender::QCuboidMesh *cuboid = new Qt3DRender::QCuboidMesh();

// CuboidMesh Transform
Qt3DCore::QTransform *cuboidTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();
cuboidTransform->setScale(4.0f);
cuboidTransform->setTranslation(QVector3D(4.0f, -4.0f, 0.0f));

Qt3DRender::QPhongMaterial *cuboidMaterial = new Qt3DRender::QPhongMaterial();
cuboidMaterial->setDiffuse(QColor(QRgb(0x665423)));

//Cuboid
m_cuboidEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(m_rootEntity);
m_cuboidEntity->addComponent(cuboid);
m_cuboidEntity->addComponent(cuboidMaterial);
m_cuboidEntity->addComponent(cuboidTransform);
```

I also tried to copy this example code, but guess, it isn't working.